# bazel: '@bazel/typescript' is not a package

Tags: typescript, bazel

My attempt loading `ts_project` fails with the error message below:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Label '@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl' is invalid because '@bazel/typescript' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@npm//:@bazel/typescript/index.bzl'?
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
workspace(
    name = "nodejs",
    managed_directories = {"@npm": ["node_modules"]},
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
    sha256 = "cfc289523cf1594598215901154a6c2515e8bf3671fd708264a6f6aefe02bf39",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/4.4.6/rules_nodejs-4.4.6.tar.gz"],
)

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "npm_install")
npm_install(
    name = "npm",
    package_json = "//:package.json",
    package_lock_json = "//:package-lock.json",
)
```

`BUILD`:

```
load("@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl", "ts_project")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "nodejs_test")

ts_project(
  name = "lib",
  srcs = glob(["src/**/*.ts"]),
  tsconfig = "tsconfig.json",
  deps = [
    "@npm//@types/lodash"
  ],
  declaration = True,
  source_map = True,
)

nodejs_test(
  name = "index_test",
  entry_point = ":src/index.ts",
  data = [
    "@npm//lodash",
    ":lib"
  ],
)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a minimal package.json that you're not showing us here, say

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Then if you check what's in `@npm`, you will see that there are no packages defined inside of it.

```
❯ bazel query @npm//...
@npm//:node_modules
Loading: 1 packages loaded
```

You'll need to add `@bazel/typescript` to your package.json to have `npm_install` make it available to you. So run

```
❯ npm install @bazel/typescript

up to date, audited 25 packages in 644ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

package.json now has

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "@bazel/typescript": "^4.4.6"
    }
}
```

and our Bazel query now shows a bunch of available packages:

```
❯ bazel query @npm//...
@npm//tsutils:tsutils__umd
@npm//tsutils:tsutils__typings
@npm//tsutils:tsutils__all_files
[...]
@npm//@bazel/typescript:typescript__nested_node_modules
@npm//@bazel/typescript:typescript__files
Loading: 0 packages loaded
```

including the one that the `load` statement was previously not finding. At this point you can try to build your package again, making sure to add all the dependencies you need (like lodash).